# Credit Card Checker does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, credit-card

I have previously had a credit card number checker on other documents. i have copied it to this new project of mine. but now it does not seem to give me an alert when it is correct or not. 
I am not sure of the cause of this as i have copy and pasted it from several working projects changed the HTML and some of the JS to try to get it to work.

what i am trying to do is when the CC number is entered and the the 'Submit' button is pressed. it will check to see if the visa credit card number entered passes the Luhn check.

when the code is run I get no error messages or anything. it just goes through on 'submit'. wither or not i have entered a number, a correct number, or an incorrect number

This is the HTML for it.

```
<!-- Start of Paymant Form -->
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                Credit Card Payments
            </legend>
            <label>
            Credit Card<span class="red">*</span>
                <select id="creditCardType" name="creditCard">
                    <option value="visa">Visa</option>
                    <option value="masterCard">Master Card</option>
                </select>
            </label>
            <label>
                Cardholder Name<span class="red">*</span> <input type="text" value="" />
            </label>
            <label>
                Card Number<span class="red">*</span> <input type="text" value=""  id="ccNum"/>
            </label>
        </fieldset
<!-- End of Payment Form -->
<!-- Start of Submit/Reset Form -->

        <fieldset>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
                <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </fieldset>
```

and this is the JavaScript of mine

```
function main() {
    "use strict"
        document.getElementById("ccNum").addEventListener("change", function() {creditCardChecker(readFromInputArea("ccNum"));});
}
function creditCardChecker(ccNum) {
    "use strict"
        var isValid=false;          //if its valid
        isValid=checkCard(ccNum);
        if (isValid) {
            alert ("Card Number " + ccNum + " is a valid credit card number")
        }
        else {
            alert ("Card Number " + ccNum + " is not a valid credit card number. Try again.")
        }

    }

function checkCard(strCardNum) {
// Check Credit Card
    "use strict";

//Var
    var intPos=strCardNum.length-1;     //The Position in the string
    var intCheckTotal=0;
    var intEvenProd=0;
    var i=1;
    for (i=1;i<=strCardNum.length;i++) { 
        if ((i%2)==1) {             //Odd Position
            intCheckTotal+=(strCardNum.charAt (intPos)-0);
        }
        else {                  //Even Position
            intEvenProd=strCardNum.charAt(intPos)*2;
            if (intEvenProd<10) {
                intCheckTotal+=(intEvenProd-0);
                }
            else {
            intCheckTotal+=(1+intEvenProd%10);
            }
        }
    intPos--;
    }
//Now Check if a valid number
    if (intCheckTotal%10==0) {
        return true;            //return  true
        //alert ("Card Number " + strCardNum + " is a valid credit card number");
    }
    else {
        return false;
        //alert("Card Number " + strCardNum + " is not a valid credit card number. Try again.")
            }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance on this.
Kind regards
Jayden.

Also on a side note. if anyone saw my last question i posted. in regards to the credit card checker. i am sorry it was so poorly asked.

Comment: I don't see the code for `readFromInputArea` but since you are already in the context of the input during your event, you might as well use `event.target.value` where `event` is passed in to the function.

Comment: Where is `main()` called from? If you call it from an onload handler (and use `this.value` instead of `readFromInputArea("ccNum")`) your code works, as you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hfd3mze9/).

Comment: You have no logic to prevent a `submit` from happening